# Can I use loop in this function?

Tags: python, function

I'm creating a function for a game which includes a board and words. I have designed this function and I don't really know if I could use a loop or a list method to run it correctly.
This is the function I am creating:

```
def make_str_from_column(board, column_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the column of the board with index column_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 1)
    'NS'
    """
```

Comment: As is, your question is very hard to understand. Where is the actual function implementation? What do you mean by list method? (I'm assuming, you mean a list **comprehension**) Also, StackOverflow is only for coding questions and we rarely take on things that already work. Questions regarding improvement should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options for getting the letters.  You could use a simple loop

```
ret = []
for sublist in board:
    ret.append(sublist[column_index])
```

You could simplify that into a list comprehension

```
[sublist[column_index] for sublist in board]
```

Or you can use `zip`, which will actually make each column, and then you can choose among them.

```
list(zip(*board))[column_index]
```

Personally, I would choose the list comprehension.

Once you have that however, you should use `''.join` to combine the list of strings into a single string

```
return ''.join([sublist[column_index] for sublist in board])
```

Comment: I think a list comprehension is better too. But in this case I have to use functions that I have created earlier. Under this conditions zip could be used  anyway? or use it could be more difficult? PD: I didn't know zip option.

Comment: @KennethRivadeneiraGuadamud You can read more about `zip` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip